# custom functions SQLite with Mono

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, mono, xamarin.ios

is there a way to add SQLite custom function using Mono? (Mono.Data.Sqlite)

I tried to add distance function that returns the distance between two geo locations

```
    [SqliteFunctionAttribute(Name = "distance", Arguments = 4, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar)]
    class SqliteDistance : SqliteFunction
    {
        public override object Invoke(object[] args)
        {
            double radius = 6367;
            double lat1 = System.Convert.ToDouble(args[0]);
            double lng1 = System.Convert.ToDouble(args[1]);
            double lat2 = System.Convert.ToDouble(args[2]);
            double lng2 = System.Convert.ToDouble(args[3]);

            return radius * 2 * Math.Asin( Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt( ( Math.Pow(Math.Sin((lat2* (Math.PI / 180) - lat1 * (Math.PI / 180) ) / 2.0), 2.0) + Math.Cos(lat1* (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.Cos(lat2* (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(( lng2* (Math.PI / 180)-lng1* (Math.PI / 180)) / 2.0), 2.0) ) ) ) ); 
        }
    }
```

and it gives me an error:

> Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteFunction:ScalarCallback (intptr,int,intptr)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.

Comment: Any examples on how to implement custom methods like this?

I need to implement acos, cos, sin and other math functions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the **Reverse Callbacks** paragraph of the page that the error reports: in practice you need to apply the MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute attribute to the method (and it needs to be made static).

This is a limitation on iOS devices, because they don't support JIT compilers.